# @media width size stuck at 960px?

Tags: css, media-queries

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 0px) 
  and (max-device-width: 374px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { }
```

for my media query I need the max-width to be 374px but my width is stuck at 960px no matter what. I tried to adjust both the width and max-width to 100% or 374px.

Answer (score 0):

The media query is used for applying certain **CSS styles** based on the device width. The media query itself doesn't set values, but **detects the device width**. They work like this ([source](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_media_queries_demystified_min-width_and_max-width)):

**Min-width means**: "If [device width] is greater than or equal to [specified #], then do {...}"

**Max-width means**: "If [device width] is less than or equal to [specified #], then do {...}"

So in your case, you probably want to do something like this:

```
@media only screen 
  and (max-device-width: 374px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {     
   .container {
     width: 374px;
   }    
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that not solving my issue, my wrapper div's ( the outer most div that has all containing divs inside) width is set to 374px and still the width is showing up as 960px on the dev tools

Comment: Can you submit your code to http://www.jsfiddle.net ? Without code it's hard to see what exactly the problem is.

Comment: there are some images included in the file, the code seems to be broken on jsfiddle

Comment: You may want to upload the images to some image uploading service then, or strip them from the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `max-device-width` property as opposed to the `max-width` property. There is a big difference between the two:

1. `max-device-width`: refers to the actual width of the screen someone is using, i.e. - the physical size of the screen in their hands. This is important as some devices for example can cram more than 2 "CSS" pixels into one device pixel. It also doesn't take into account browser resizing, it sticks only to the screen size regardless of other factors.
2. `max-width`: refers to the viewport of the screen, i.e. if someone resizes their browser window you can target exactly that viewport size.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi,**

Dunno if you still need the answer, but for whoever read this post looking for similar solutions, I would like to share my five cents in regards to this scenario. **Don't forget** to run the code in full screen mode so that you can test its result. Keep coding, fellows!

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    height: 300px;
    width: 374px;
}

.subtitle{
font-size: 14px;
font-weight:normal;
color: #33CC78;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 374px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .container {
        background-color: green;
        color: yellow;
        height: 250px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>
  BASIC DEMO <br /> 
  <span class="subtitle">CSS is the coolest thing</span>
  </h2>
</div>
```